# HTML File Not Posting

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can not for the life of me figure out why this file is not being posted. I have already looked all for solutions to this. I have checked all of my ini file variables and they are fine. I also have the correct form type. I am also using bootstrap for the buttons on this.

```
<form id="secureorder" class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="process.php">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <span id="FileRxButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
              Select Prescription...
            </span>
        </span>

        <input id="FileRxName" name="FileRxName" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" placeholder="optional">
        <input id="FileRx" name="FileRx" type="file" style="display: none;" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I use `print_r($_POST)` in the PHP file all form values are showing up except for the file inputs. The way I am trying to get it to work is where the file input is hidden and the text field is just a dummy field for the file name so it looks nice.

Here is the javascript im using

```
$(function() {
    $("#FileRxButton").click(function() { $("#FileRx").click(); });
    $('input#FileRx').change(function() { $('#FileRxName').val($(this).val()); });
});
```

Comment: Where is the submit button? how are you submitting the form?

Comment: I see no button, it is span

Comment: it is possible to submit a form without a submit button with javascript but not that javascript ^^

Comment: Just forgot to put it in the question. Its funny how everyone on here assumes if its not on the question its not actually there lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a mystery to me how anything gets posted with the code you posted above, but anyway you'll find the files under `$_FILES` not `$_POST`

Try :

```
 var_dump($_FILES);
```

Comment: Ah yes. I have not uploaded anything in forever, forgot about that. Thanks! I figured it was something stupid like that.